# function pointer with known arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a lot of legacy code that uses a function pointer as an argument of the form `double (*f)(double)`. Now I have a requirement where I need to call this function from a class but function definition uses member variables. What do I do to solve this issue? For example,

```
void legacy_function(double (*f)(double)) { .... }

class myclass {
   double a;
   double b;
   double c;

   void mymethod(...) {
       // need to call legacy_function() such that it uses a and b with one unknown
       // a+b*x

   }
```

Note that I cannot change definitions or declarations in legacy code.

I hope this is making sense. thanks for suggestions..

Comment: If you could change the legacy code, boost::function would fit. See 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1264562

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no clean way to solve this problem. It has no elegant solution within the bounds of the standard language.

One thing you can do is to provide a global or static variable that will serve as `this` pointer for the intermediate callback wrapper function (see below), and write a static intermediate callback wrapper function which will delecate the call to a non-static class method

```
class myclass {
  ...
  static myclass *myclass_this;

  double callback_wrapper(double d) {
    assert(myclass_this != NULL);
    return myclass_this->callback(d); // calls the actual implementation
  }
};
```

Also write the actual callback implementation in `myclass`

```
class myclass {
  ...
  double callback(double d) {
    // do whatever you want with `a`, `b` etc.
    return /* whatever */;
  }
  ...
};
```

Now you can initialize `myclass_this` and use the intermediate callback wrapper from inside `mymethod`

```
...
void mymethod(...) {
  myclass_this = this; // initilize the context
  legacy_function(&callback_wrapper);
}
...
```

All this, of course, is terribly inelegant since it relies on global or static variables and therefore is non-reentrant.

There are alternative methods, which all happen to be non-portable and non-standard. (Read about *closures* and *[delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx)*).